# Asymptotic behavior of the minimum eigenvalue of a certain Gram matrix with linear independence

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, asymptotics, quantum-calculus

Consider the density matrices with the following spectral decompositions:
$$\rho=\lambda_1|\nu_1\rangle+\lambda_{2}|\nu_2\rangle$$
and
$$\sigma=\gamma_1|\omega_1\rangle+\gamma_2|\omega_2\rangle$$
such that $\gamma_i=\lambda_i$ and $\lambda_1>\lambda_2$. Also because $\rho$ and $\sigma$ are density matrices we have $\lambda_1+\lambda_2 = \gamma_1 + \gamma_2 = 1$. Also for the two ONBs $V_1=\{|\nu_{1}\rangle,|\nu_2\rangle\}$ and $V_2 = \{|\omega_1\rangle,|\omega_2\rangle\}$ we have:
$$|\nu_1\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|\omega_1\rangle+|\omega_2\rangle)$$
and
$$|\nu_2\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|\omega_1\rangle - |\omega_2\rangle)$$

It is clear that $V_{1,2}^{\otimes n}$ stay mutually unbiased namely for all $|\omega_i\rangle\in V_2^{\otimes n}$ and $|\nu_j\rangle\in V_1^{\otimes n}$ we have:
$$|\langle \omega_i \mid \nu_j\rangle|^2 = \frac{1}{2^n}$$
Consider the set $U$, the union of eigenvectors of $\rho^{\otimes n}$ and $\sigma^{\otimes n}$. From this union set choose the $2^n$ linearly independent vectors with largest eigenvalues. Call this newly acquired set of cardinality $2^n$ $\Sigma^{(n)}$. When $n$ is odd we expect $\Sigma^{(n)}$ to have half of its elements from each basis. Assign a Gram matrix to $\Sigma^{(n)}$. This Gram matrix, at least for odd values of $n$ will have a nice 2 by 2 block structure with diagonal identity blocks and off-diagonal blocks of order $2^{n-1}$: 
$$\Gamma^{(n)}=\left( \begin{array}{cc}
  I & B \\
  B^{*} & I
  \end{array} \right)$$
Also the off-diagonal block $B$ and its conjugate have entries all equal to $\pm\frac{1}{\sqrt{2^{n}}}$. The question is: what can we say about the asymptotic behavior of the minimum eigenvalue of $\Gamma^{(n)}$. I hope to see if it decreases polynomially with $n$ rather than exponentially. Yet better it might even be a constant. For instance if $\hat{B}=2^{\frac{n}{2}}B$ is a Hadamard matrix it will be $\frac{1}{2}$. Of course given the problem it cannot be. $\hat{B}$ is however a submatrix of a Hadamard matrix of order $2^n$. I think the best bounds might be obtained  considering that $B$ is a symmetric matrix.

Comment: Where you write $|\nu_1 >{}$, did you mean $|\nu_1\rangle\  {}$? ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: yes I did. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Aren't the eigenvalues of $\Gamma$ always $1\pm \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$?  <s>I'm confused as to why you're asking for asymptotics (and why you say this is only interesting for odd $n$).</s>

If we express $\rho$ and $\sigma$ using coordinates in the $\omega$ basis, they are
$R=Q_R \Lambda Q_R^*$ and $S=Q_S \Lambda Q_S^*$ where
$$\Lambda = \left[\begin{array}{cc} \lambda_1 & 0 \\ 0 & \lambda_2 \end{array}\right] = \Lambda_R = \Lambda_S$$
$$Q_R = \left[\begin{array}{cc} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \\ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \end{array}\right] = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}H_2$$
$$Q_S = \left[\begin{array}{cc} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{array}\right] = I_2$$
and $H_2$ is the $2\times 2$ Hadamard matrix.

$R$ has eigenvalues $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$.  $R^{\otimes n}$ has eigenvalues
$\lambda_1^i \lambda_2^{n-i}$ with $i\in {0,\ldots ,n}$ and multiplicity
$\left(\begin{array}{c} n \\ i \end{array} \right)$.  ((Clarification: This lists the eigenvalues in increasing order; it is simply the
reverse of them in decreasing order.  The multiplicities are correct regardless; the
binomial coefficients are symmetric.  Note that *neither* of these orderings is the
order in which the eigenvalues appear along the diagonal of $\Lambda^{\otimes n}$.
See below.))  We also know the eigenvectors:
$$R^{\otimes n} = \left(Q_R^{\otimes n}\right) \left(\Lambda^{\otimes n}\right) \left(Q_R^{\otimes n}\right)^*$$
where
$$\begin{array}{rcl} Q_R^{\otimes n} &=& 2^{-n/2} H_2^{\otimes n} \\ &=& 2^{-n/2} \left[\begin{array}{cc} H_2^{\otimes n-1} & H_2^{\otimes n-1} \\ H_2^{\otimes n-1} & -H_2^{\otimes n-1} \end{array}\right]\end{array}$$
We also have that $S^{\otimes n} = \Lambda^{\otimes n}$ (and $Q_S^{\otimes n}=I_{2^n}$).  Note using the Kronecker product here mirrors the Sylvester construction for (real) Hadamard matrices.

We know $\lambda_1^i \lambda_2^{n-i} > \lambda_1^j \lambda_2^{n-j}$ whenever $i>j$.
(I'm assuming that in addition to $\lambda_1>\lambda_2$ and $\lambda_1+\lambda_2=1$,
you also meant $\lambda_1,\lambda_2\geq 0$.)  ((Clarification: This is correct as stated.  Note this is purely an algebraic
statement about the $\lambda_i$'s.  It has nothing to do with their being eigenvalues
or the ordering thereof.))  Then the eigenvectors of $R^{\otimes
n}$ <s>with largest magnitude are always</s> the first $2^{n-1}$ ones.  For $R^{\otimes n}$,
that's $2^{-n/2} \left[\begin{array}{c} H_2^{\otimes n-1} \\ H_2^{\otimes n-1} \end{array}\right]$,
and for $S^{\otimes n}$, that's $\left[\begin{array}{c} I_{2^{n-1}} \\ 0 \end{array}\right]$.

That makes $B=2^{-n/2} H_2^{\otimes n-1}$.  From [your other
question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1330576/determinant-of-a-certain-block-structured-positive-definite-matrix)
and my answer there, we know the eigenvalues of $\Gamma$ are $1\pm \sigma$ where
$\sigma$ is a singular value of $B$.  But the singular values of $H_2^{\otimes n-1}$
are all $2^{(n-1)/2}$ so the singular values of $B$ are all $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$.
That makes the eigenvalues of $\Gamma$ all $1\pm \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$.

#### A different example

A word of caution applies, though.  Suppose for the sake of argument you allow $Q_R$
to be any orthonormal basis, $R$ to be of any dimension, and free yourself to choose
any columns of $Q_R$ to form $B$.

The columns of any (complex) Hadamard matrix represent a scaled version of a basis that is mutually
unbiased with respect to the standard basis.  Also, if $H_n$ is a Hadamard matrix (of dimension
$n$), then so is
$$\hat{H}_{2n} = \left[\begin{array}{cc} H_n & H_n \\ H_n & -H_n \end{array}\right]$$.
(This is the Sylvester construction.)

If we are free to choose any columns we please in constructing $\Gamma$, then we can
always choose them from $\hat{H}_{2n}$ so that $\Gamma$ is singular.  Pick $n/2$
columns from the first $n$ columns, and then pick corresponding columns from the
second $n$ columns: if the $i$th column is chosen, then also choose column $i+n$.

This doesn't meet one of your other criteria: that the columns chosen have their first-half components linearly independent.  However, we can use the ideas above to construct columns whose first-halves are nearly dependent (as nearly singular as you choose).  Let
$$H(\theta) = \frac{1}{2} \left[\begin{array}{cccc} 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & ie^{i\theta} & -1 & -ie^{i\theta} \\ 1 & -1 & 1 & -1 \\ 1 & -ie^{i\theta} & -1 & ie^{i\theta} \end{array}\right]$$.
This is a one-parameter family of (scaled) Hadamard matrices of order 4.  The first principal
$2\times 2$ submatrix has singular values:
$$\sigma = \left\{\frac{1}{2} \pm \frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}\left(1-\sin x\right)^{1/2}\right\}^{1/2}$$.
By choosing $\theta=-\pi / 2 + \epsilon$, we can make the lesser singular value vanishingly small , and the larger one arbitrarily close to 1.
For $\epsilon\ll 1$, the smaller singular value is approximately $\epsilon/4$ (and the larger is $1-\epsilon/4$).

This construction can be extended to higher dimensions.  For example, the matrix
$$\left[\begin{array}{cc} H_{\theta} & H_{\theta +\epsilon} \\ H_{\phi} & -H_{\phi +\epsilon} \end{array} \right]$$
has columns 2, 4, 6, and 8 that are linearly independent and that have first halves that are linearly independent.
But, as above, the matrix $B$ of the first halves of these columns has singular values as close as desired to 0 or 1.

**EDIT:** OK.  I've made a correction above along with a couple of clarifications.  I've also replied to and expanded on the comments below.

As constructed above, the values along the diagonal of $\Lambda^{\otimes n}$ -- the
eigenvalues -- appear in binary order of the states.  For $n=3$ this is: 000, 001,
010, 011, 100, 101, 110, and 111.  This arises naturally out of the Kronecker
product ($\otimes$).  However, it's not the order you're asking for.  You say you want the states
sorted by [Hamming distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_distance) from the
origin.  For $n=3$ this is: 000, 001, 010, 100, 011, 101, 110, and 111.  Note that
this ordering is ambiguous for even $n$ whereas the binary ordering is always
unambiguous.

You want $B$ to  be a principal submatrix of a   permutation (symmetrically of both the
rows and columns) of the Kronecker product/power $Q_R^{\otimes n}$.  I'm not sure if
this has a name (and, of course, it's not the natural one that arises out of the
Kronecker product, the one I analyzed above).  But now that I know what you're asking
for, I can recompute and edit this answer.

To restate the example in the comments below, for $n=3$    the binary order results in
$$2\sqrt{2}B = \left[\begin{array}{cccc}1&1&1&1\\1&-1&1&-1\\1&1&-1&-1\\1&-1&-1&1\end{array}\right]$$
whereas the Hamming sort results in
$$2\sqrt{2}B = \left[\begin{array}{cccc}1&1&1&1\\1&-1&1&1\\1&1&-1&1\\1&1&1&-1\end{array}\right]$$
(which is unambiguous regardless of the subsort of 001, 010, 100).

**EDIT:** I haven't been able to find an analytic expression for the smallest
eigenvalue of $\Gamma$ for arbitrary $n$ nor an analytic expression for the
asymptotic value as $n$ gets large.  However, I have been able to find a reduction of
the problem that allowed me to compute exact values up to $n=9$ and approximate
values up to $n=21$.  I thought I'd post those results so you don't keep waiting.

As noted before, the smallest eigenvalue of $\Gamma$ is $1$ minus the largest
singular value (closest to $1$) of $B$.  The right singular vector corresponding to
this value has the form
$\left[\begin{array}{cccccc}1&x_1&x_2&x_3&\cdots&x_{(n-1)/2}\end{array}\right]$ where
$1$ is repeated once, $x_1$ is repeated $n$ times, $x_2$ is repeated
$\left(\begin{array}{c}n\\2\end{array}\right)$ times, $x_3$ is repeated
$\left(\begin{array}{c}n\\3\end{array}\right)$ times, and so on.  For the largest
singular value, the $x_n$'s are all positive.  (Other singular vectors also have this
form, but not all do.)  Using this ansatz, we can reduce the $2^{n-1}\times 2^{n-1}$ eigensystem for
$B$ down to a $\frac{n+1}{2}\times\frac{n+1}{2}$ system.

I was able to find exact values for $n$ equal to 3, 5, 7, and 9.  The smallest
eigenvalue of $\Gamma$ is $1-2^{-n/2}\phi_n$ for $\phi_n$ in the following table:

$$\begin{array}{r|c}
n&\phi_n\\ \hline
3& 1+\sqrt{3} \\
5& 3+\sqrt{7} \\
7& 1+\sqrt{21}+\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{168-8\sqrt{21}} \\
9& \frac{1}{2}\left( \sqrt{2\sqrt{561}+462} + \sqrt{561} - 1 \right)
\end{array}$$

I was able to find approximate values up to $n=21$.  The smallest eigenvalues are `3.4074e-2`, `1.9627e-3`, `8.5098e-5`, `3.2961e-6`, `1.2022e-7`, `4.2208e-9`, `1.443097e-10`, `4.83855e-12`, `1.5987e-13`, and `5.28402e-15`.  If we make a log-log plot of them versus $m=2^n$, we get nearly a straight line:

[image: Log-log of smallest eigenvalue vs. $m=2^n$]

A fitted line gives $\lambda\approx Cm^{-2.5}$.  This is monomial in $m$, but not in $n$ as you asked.  In terms of $n$, this is $\lambda\approx C2^{-2.5n}$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm not convinced that $B=2^{n-1}H_{2}^{\otimes n-1}$. A counter example is $n=3$: The Gram matrix will be assigned to $\{|\nu_{1,1,1}>,|\nu_{1,1,2}>,|\nu_{1,2,1}>,|\nu_{2,1,1}>, |\omega_{1,1,1}>,|\omega_{1,1,2}>,|\omega_{1,2,1}>,|\omega_{2,1,1}>\}$ where the indexes specify tensor product strings (this is an example why $n$ has to be odd for equal selection of vectors from each basis). Now $B=4^{-1}\{1,1,1,1\},\{1,-1,1,1\},\{1,1,-1,1\},\{1,1,1,-1\}$ where each set is a row. @Armadillo Jim

Comment: That is not a Hadamard matrix.

Comment: The only special structure that exists in $B$ is that rows corresponding to even values of $i$ (in $\lambda_{1}^{n-i}\lambda_{2}^{i}$) are orthogonal to each other. So are the rows corresponding to odd values of $i$. But rows corresponding to odd values are not necessarily orthogonal to the ones corresponding to even values of $i$.

Comment: I've rolled back your edit to my answer.  I don't think you're seeing the symmetry there.

Comment: About your first comment, I said $B=2^{-n/2}H_2^{\otimes n-1}$.  Where are you getting $2^{n-1}$?  Also, isn't $B=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}\left[\begin{array}{cccc}1&1&1&1\\1&-1&1&-1\\1&1&-1&-1\\1&-1&-1&1\end{array}\right]$ for $n=3$?  I'm understanding $\otimes$ as the [Kronecker product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product).  Is that not what you mean?  What full columns are there in the matrix of eigenvectors of $\rho^{\otimes 3}$?

Comment: yes I should have said $2^{-n/2}$. No for $n=3$ $B=2^{-3/2}\{1,1,1,1\},\{1,-1,1,1\},\{1,1,-1,1\},\{1,1,1,-1\}$ given the selected vectors I gave in my comment. This is because we have $-1$ whenever an odd number of $2$-indexes match. For instance $<\omega_{1,2}|\nu_{1,2}>=<\omega_{1}|\nu_{1}><\omega_{2}|\nu_{2}>=-\frac{1}{2}$. This is true about $n$ indexes.

Comment: Only $<\omega_{2}|\nu_{2}>$ gives us a negative contribution. @Armadillo Jim

Comment: Also, I don't see why you rolled back my edit. $\lambda_{1}>\lambda_{2}$ therefore $\lambda_{1}^{n-i}\lambda_{2}^{i}$ has the order from the largest eigenvalue to the smallest not $\lambda_{1}^{i}\lambda_{2}^{n-i}$ for $i=0,...,n$. @Armadillo Jim

Comment: Do you see why we choose $\{|\nu_{1,1,1}>,|\nu_{1,1,2}>,|\nu_{1,2,1}>,|\nu_{2,1,1}>, |\omega_{1,1,1}>,|\omega_{1,1,2}>,|\omega_{1,2,1}>,|\omega_{2,1,1}>\}$? Do you agree with this selection?

Comment: Mr. Smithson, the eigenvalues are correct for the states in binary order.  I did say I would recompute and edit the answer for them in Hamming order.  Please take it easy.  I do this recreationally and don't appreciate your tone.

Comment: Sorry sir I didn't mean to come across as rude and I hadn't read the last lines of your edit. I appreciate your answers they have been very enlightening. @Armadillo Jim

Comment: If we show that the set of the first $2^{n-1}$ Hamming vectors is a sub-set of the set of the first $\frac{3}{4}2^{n}$ binary (tensor product) vectors the problem is solved. @Armadillo Jim